# Tensor product with zero

Tags: tensors

I am calculating the huge sums, that include tensor products and I noticed that Mathematica does not simplify the tensor products of the form $A \otimes 0 \otimes C$, and also it does not simplify the coefficients, like $\frac{1}{16} (-2A) \otimes B $. How can I fix it? Commands like "FullSimplify" or "TensorReduce" do not help, and when there are about 70 terms in the sum, it is very problematic to remove the extra zero terms just by hand.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include some of the probelmatic code?  That would help us diagnose and fix the problem in an easy way by copying and pasting the code into our own copies of Mathematica.

Comment: @march well I am just using the typesetting function, so it looks exactly the same as in the post, for example, A\[CircleTimes]0\[CircleTimes]C, if copying as a code

Comment: Correct syntax will solve the problem: `TensorProduct[A0 \.08, TensorProduct[0, C]]`evaluates to `0`

Comment: Try `TensorProduct[A,0,C]`.

Comment: The `FullForm` of $A \otimes 0 \otimes C$ is `CircleTimes[A,0,C]`, and the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleTimes.html) says that this “has no meaning”. It is not interpreted as a tensor product.